# Removing the Z from geometry?

Tags: openlayers

In openlayers3, is there a method for removing the Z when getting the coordinates of a feature with layout=XYZ?  Something akin to this but built into ol3?

```
function strip(geom, test) {
    if (!geom.length) return;
    if (typeof geom[0] !== "number") {
        return geom.map(function(g) { return strip(g, test); });
    }
    return geom.filter(test);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Lacking a better answer, here's a custom solution that seems to be working:

```
function strip(geom, test: (a, b) => boolean) {
if (!geom.length) return;
if (typeof geom[0] !== "number") {
    return geom.map(g => strip(g, test));
}
return geom.filter(test);
```

}

Usage:

```
coords = geom.getCoordinates();
if (geom.stride > 2) {
    strip(coords, (v, i) => 2 > i % geom.stride);
}
```